# Seeing weird icon for Google maps in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I updated google maps sdk for my iOS project and I am seeing this weird icon for current location.My updated Google Maps SDK version is: 1.12.23211.0

[image]

Comment: are you test this in simulator or in real device?

Comment: It is coming both in simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I forgot to replace GoogleMaps.bundle while I was replacing framework.After replacing everything worked as expected.